# How to create a function to normalize my variables

Tags: r

At first, i have created my function( `normaliser_vecteur`) which has a single input parameter.The Data parameter: vector of data to be standardized I created it from this formula:

```
I=X-Xmin/Xmax-Xmin
normaliser_vecteur=function(x){ 
 i= x-min(x)/max(x)-min(x)
 return(i)
}
```

This is my first function and it works.

This is my dataframe's head:
[image: This is my dataframe's head]

I want now to create a function( `normaliser_caracteristiques`) and it will have three input parameters:
• Data parameter: data.frame that will be used as a data source
• Parameter liste_caracteristiques: vector of the characteristics to be normalized
• fn parameter: the name of the normalization function to use
• This function should: 1. Filter the data source to retain only the requested characteristics 2. For each characteristic, normalize the variables tous_genres, genre_f and genre_h by adding three new variables norm_tous_genres, norm_genre_f and norm_genre_h

Comment: You need to have paranthesis. ie `(x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x))`

Comment: Alright,i changed it